# the best way to implement a check guess function, where the function will compare letters in guess and user word

Tags: python, sql

> Implement a function check_guess()that takes two parameters. The first
> is the guessed word and the second is the word the user has to find.
> check_guess() returns a string containing the following characters:
>
> - `X` for each character in the guess that is at the correct position.
> - `O` for each character in the guess that is in the word but not at the correct position.
> - `_` for each character in the guess that is not part of the word. For example, check_guess("birds", "words") should return `__XXX`.
>
> If a letter is used twice in the guessed word and exists only once in the
> word to be found, then only one letter in the return string is marked.
> In case one of the two letters is positioned correctly, then this
> letter is marked with an X in the return string. For example,
> check_guess("carat", "train") should return `_OO_O`. Another example,
> check_guess("taunt", "train") should return `XO_O_`

here is my code for the problem, but is not giving me the solution

```
def check_guess(guess, word):
        string = [ ]
        for i in range(len(word)):
            for j in range(len(guess)):
                if guess[j] == word[i]:
                    string.append("x")
                elif guess[j] != word[i]:
                    string.append("0")
                elif i != j:
                    string.append("_")
                else:
                    print(string)
                    return string
    guess = "train"
    word = "after"
    print(check_guess("train","after"))
```

Comment: whats the point of the 'strong text' above?

Comment: Please, fix the indentation. Make sure people can copy-paste your code and have it working. Also, why did you use the tag "sql"? this is clearly not a question about SQL.

Comment: You're returning `string` only when no other condition is fulfilled (`return` is in the body of the last `else`). Also, you're appending "_" every time i is not equal to j, independently of whether there was a match or not. Probably you were trying to nest conditionals??

Comment: If this is homework, I would say check my comment before and make sure the code does something, even if it's not what you want. Also search the internet for the "in" and "not in" operators.

Answer (score 1):

The caveat at the bottom make this a bit trickier than the others, but I think the easiest way to test this would be to take advantage of a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Start by creating a Counter using the letters required in the final word:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> letters = Counter(word)
>>> letters
Counter({'t': 1, 'r': 1, 'a': 1, 'i': 1, 'n': 1})
```

As we loop through each letter in the `guess` we can remove values from this counter. Only place the `O` if we haven't already exhausted all the occurrences of a particular letters in the original word, otherwise print the `_`.

We'll also want to first subtract all of the letters that are already in the correct spot first, to ensure we don't count a single letter more than we should.

To collect the results, we can use a list, and then `str.join` them together.

```
from collections import Counter

guess, word = "taunt", "train"

letters = Counter(word)
answer = [""] * len(word)

for i, letter in enumerate(guess):
    if word[i] == letter:
        answer[i] = "X"
        letters.subtract(letter)

for i, letter in enumerate(guess):
    # We already handled this above.
    if word[i] == letter:
        continue

    if letters[letter] > 0:
        answer[i] = "O"
        letters.subtract(letter)
    else:
        answer[i] = "_"

print(''.join(answer))
```

Comment: It doesn't work with "taunte", "train" :)

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly those words are of unequal length. I'll leave OP to handle any necessary edge cases.